# Как правильно подключить клиент к серверу? (React + Express)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, сервер, express

Вопрос философского характера:
Разработал проект, клиент- React, сервер - Express.
Во время разработки использовал:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join('../food-blog/build')));
```

Столкнулся с тем что, при обновлении страницы вне зависимости по какому url я нахожусь, вместо нужной страницы выводило:`Cannot GET /[url]`

Так же знаю о варианте , как указать `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"`.
С ним все работает. Тем не менее хотел бы узнать, какой способ является корректным как с техничской, так и логической стороны. Буду рад любому ресурсу или ответу!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас запускался express сервер и create-react-app на 3000 порту, поэтому при proxy все работало